# ValueError when creating Scatter in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Below is my code where I query my database, assign it to a dataframe, and then attempt to graph the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import plotly.express as px

query1 = "select *, profit/count_emails as profit_per_email from (select days, sum(profit) as profit, count(*) as count_emails from chart_view group by days) x order by profit_per_email desc"

df1 = pd.read_sql(query1, conn)

fig = px.scatter(df1, x='days', y='profit_per_email', size = 'profit')
fig.show()
```

When I leave off size = 'profit', the chart works. However, when I add size = 'profit' the chart gives me a value error. Why might this be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For most database servers, `SUM` returns `NULL` when applied on no rows.

**MySQL database**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

**Postgres database**

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html

> It should be noted that **except for count, these functions return a null value when no rows are selected**. In particular, sum of no rows returns null, not zero as one might expect, and array_agg returns null rather than an empty array when there are no input rows. The coalesce function can be used to substitute zero or an empty array for null when necessary.

This is leading to `NaN` value in the 'profit' column in your DataFrame.

You can confirm this by checking the result of:

```py
df1['profit'].isnull().values.any()
```

I suggest that you apply the `COALESCE` function to the SUM result.

```py
query1 = """
    SELECT *, profit/count_emails AS profit_per_email 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            days,
            COALESCE(SUM(profit), 0) AS profit, 
            COUNT(*) AS count_emails
        FROM chart_view GROUP BY days
    ) AS x 
    ORDER BY profit_per_email DESC
    """
```